# Norm of a Multivector in $\wedge \mathbb{R}^3$ for calculating the arrea of a polygon.

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, geometric-algebras

I am writing some code to explore some interesting things in Geometric Algebra. The general element of my code is multivector $\wedge \mathbb{R}^3$ that forms an 8-dimensional block vector with components

$${\bf x} = \pmatrix{ s \text{ : scalar} \\ \boldsymbol{v} \text{ : vector} \\ \boldsymbol{\omega} \text{ : antivector} \\ \sigma \text{ : antiscalar}} $$

<sub>Note that I am using the term anti-vector for the bivectors, and the term anti-scalar for the pseudoscalar.</sub>

and corresponding basis vectors:

$$ {\rm basis} = \pmatrix{ \{ 1 \} \\ \{ \boldsymbol{e}_1, \boldsymbol{e}_2,\boldsymbol{e}_3\} \\ \{ \overline{ \boldsymbol{e}}_{1}, \overline{\boldsymbol{e}}_{2},\overline{\boldsymbol{e}}_{3}\} \\ \{ \mathtt{i} \}} $$

where $\overline{\boldsymbol{e}}_{k} \equiv \boldsymbol{e}_i \wedge \boldsymbol{e}_j$ and  $\mathtt{i} \equiv \boldsymbol{e}_1\wedge\boldsymbol{e}_2\wedge\boldsymbol{e}_3$ for brevity.

I have the geometric and wedge products between multivectors defined according to available literature, and I also have the dot product defined as follows

$$ {\bf x}_1  \cdot {\bf x}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}s_{1}\\
            \boldsymbol{v}_{1}\\
            \boldsymbol{\omega}_{1}\\
            \sigma_{1}
            \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}s_{2}\\
            \boldsymbol{v}_{2}\\
            \boldsymbol{\omega}_{2}\\
            \sigma_{2}            \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}s_{1}s_{2}+\boldsymbol{v}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}_{2}-\boldsymbol{\omega}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{\omega}_{2}-\sigma_{1}\sigma_{2}\\
            \boldsymbol{v}_{1}s_{2}+s_{1}\boldsymbol{v}_{2}-\sigma_{1}\boldsymbol{\omega}_{2}-\boldsymbol{\omega}_{1}\sigma_{2}\\
\boldsymbol{\omega}_{1}s_{2}+\sigma_{1}\boldsymbol{v}_{2}+s_{1}\boldsymbol{\omega}_{2}+\boldsymbol{v}_{1}\sigma_{2}\\
            \sigma_{1}s_{2}+\boldsymbol{\omega}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}_{2}+\boldsymbol{v}_{1}\cdot\boldsymbol{\omega}_{2}+s_{1}\sigma_{2}
            \end{bmatrix} $$

The problem arises when I need to define the magnitude of ${\bf x}$ as

$$\|{\bf x}\| = \sqrt{ \left( {\bf x}\cdot{\bf x} \right)_{\rm scalar} } = \sqrt{ s^2+\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}-\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\boldsymbol{\omega}-\sigma^2} $$

The problem I have is that if I am getting the magnitude of an anti-vector (bivector) the result will be an imaginary number (anti-scalar).

So I have a situation where I want to calculate the area of a triangle defined by three verices ${\bf x}_i = \pmatrix{ 0 & \boldsymbol{v}_i & \boldsymbol{0} & 0}$ with $i=1\ldots 3$. The area of a convex polygon is Geometric Algebra is defined as

> <sub>Geometric Algebra for Physicists, Doran, Lasenby, 2003.</sub>
> $$ {\rm area}({\bf x}_0,\,{\bf x}_1,\ldots,{\bf x}_n) = \tfrac{1}{2} \| {\bf x}_0 \wedge {\bf x}_1 + {\bf x}_1 \wedge {\bf x}_2 + \ldots + {\bf x}_n \wedge {\bf x}_0 \| $$

In the case of a triangle, or any polygon, any ${\bf x}_i \wedge {\bf x}_{i+1}$ term results in an anit-vector, since the only non-zero parts of the multivector ${\bf x}_i$ is the vector $\boldsymbol{v}_i$

So you end up with an area formula

$$\require{cancel} {\rm area} = \tfrac{1}{2} \| \boldsymbol{\omega} \| = \sqrt{ \cancel{s^2}+\cancel{\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}}-\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\boldsymbol{\omega}-\cancel{\sigma^2}} = \tfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{ - \boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot \boldsymbol{\omega} } $$

where $\boldsymbol{\omega} = \sum_{i=0}^n \boldsymbol{v}_i \wedge \boldsymbol{v}_{i+1}$  is entirely in the bi-vector space.

**So area is obviously not a *real* number**.

This kind of surprised me, and less to ask where in the above chain of thinking I might have gone wrong.

In summary, calculating the area of a triangle using geometric algebra yields an imaginary number. My best guess is the calculation of the norm of a multivector, and honestly, I have found conflicting information on this online.

Comment: Your post hasn't presented the definition you're using for the dot product between two antivectors. That definition would help pin down your error.

Comment: The norm of $X$ is not $\sqrt{\langle XX\rangle_0}$ but $\sqrt{\langle X\,X^\sim\rangle_0}$; one factor should be reversed. Alternatively, take the absolute value.

Comment: What do you mean _reversed_? What would that look like in terms of $$\|{\bf x}\| = \sqrt{ \left( {\bf x}\cdot{\bf x} \right)_{\rm scalar} } = \sqrt{ s^2+\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}-\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot\boldsymbol{\omega}-\sigma^2}
$$

Comment: If $X=\langle X\rangle_k$ is a $k$-vector (e.g. a bivector with $k=2$), then the reverse is $X^\sim=(-1)^{k(k-1)/2}X$. Reversion is linear, $(X+Y)^\sim=X^\sim+Y^\sim$, and it reverses products, $(XY)^\sim=Y^\sim X^\sim$. In particular, if $X=(abc\cdots)$ is a product of vectors, then $X^\sim\,X=(\cdots cbaabc\cdots)=(a^2b^2c^2\cdots)\geq0$.

Comment: @mr_e_man - I don't understand your notation. If $X^\sim = -X$  for $k=3$ (3d multivectors) then $\| X \| = \sqrt{ -X \cdot X}$ which would result in a negative in the radical for real vectors. Also note that in the definition of the norm I am using the dot product, and you seem to indicate to use the geometric product.

Comment: @mr_e_man - can you show what the norm of $${\bf x} = \left( s, \boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{\omega},\sigma \right)$$ should be in terms of the components, scalar $a$, vector $\boldsymbol{v}$, bivector $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ and pseudoscalar $\sigma$?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the geometric product. $k$ is the grade of a multivector, not the dimension of space. Scalars are grade $0$, vectors are grade $1$, bivectors are grade $2$, and trivectors are grade $3$. So the reverse of $(s,v,\omega,\sigma)$ is $(s,v,-\omega,-\sigma)$.

Comment: The norm turns out to be the usual Euclidean one, the square root of the sum of squares of $8$ real numbers.

Comment: @mr_e_man - ok, now I understand. Thank you. The trick is $${\bf x}^\sim = \left( s, \boldsymbol{v},-\boldsymbol{\omega},-\sigma \right)$$ and $$ \| {\bf x} \| = \sqrt{ {\bf x}\, {\bf x}^\sim }$$

Comment: Well, you need to take the scalar part (that's what I meant by $\langle\cdot\rangle_0$). For example, if $X=s+v$, then $X^\sim=X$, and $XX=s^2+v^2+2sv$; this has a vector part $\langle XX\rangle_1=2sv$ which we don't want.

Comment: @mr_e_man - yes, I just forgot it in the comments $$| {\bf x} \| = \sqrt{ ( {\bf x}\, {\bf x}^\sim)_{\rm scalar} }$$

Comment: @mr_e_man if you just put this in an answer, I will award it.